# NSMutableAttributedString to UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to make extra characters in textfield red, so I used NSMutableAttributedString, could anyone please show me how can I transfer a NSMutableAttributedString to UITextField

```
    @IBOutlet weak var inputLimitField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var characterCountLabel: UILabel!

    private let allowedChars = 10
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        characterCountLabel.text = "10/10"
        inputLimitField.delegate = self

    }
    

    func checkRemainingChars() {
        let charsInTextView = -(inputLimitField.text?.count ?? 0)
        let remainingChars = allowedChars + charsInTextView
        characterCountLabel.textColor = .black
        inputLimitField.textColor = .black
        inputLimitField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray6.cgColor
        if remainingChars < 0 {
                getColoredText(text: inputLimitField.text ?? "") // how to implement this NSMutableAttributedString in inputLimitField.text
                characterCountLabel.textColor = .red
                inputLimitField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                inputLimitField.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
                inputLimitField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            }
        characterCountLabel.text = ("\(String(remainingChars))/10")

        }
    
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        checkRemainingChars()
    }
    
    func getColoredText(text:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString{
        let string:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        string.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: allowedChars, length: string.length))
        return string
    }
```

Comment: Samo, samo, samo at least for the 3rd time...  You are not setting an attributed string from the getColoredText guy to the text field.  What's the following for?  characterCountLabel.textColor = .red

Answer (score 2):

`getColoredText` returns the attributed string. Just assign it to the `attributedText` property of the text field

```
inputLimitField.attributedText = getColoredText(text: inputLimitField.text!)
```

Note: the `text` property of `UITextField` is never `nil`. You can forced unwrap it.